# Exchanging data between 2 languages

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to pass data from C to python. I've hit a brick wall doing it with beanstalk. My last option is sockets.

Are they any fast queue daemons around which have client libraries for both C and python?

Edit:
Operating System: Ubuntu
Solved: Check comment by Yossarian

Edit2:
libbeanstalkclient, the C client for beanstalk is spewing errors like these -> [link](http://pastebin.com/ji32ckPH)
Solved: Check comment by Yossarian

Comment: Do you have one Python application and one C application running independently? Or do you simply want Python code to be called from C code?

Comment: Would wrapping the C data with extension types (written in C with the CPython API or in Cython) be an option?

Comment: @kotlinski I have both applications running independently

Comment: "I've hit a brick wall doing it with beanstalk"?  Really?  What does this mean?  What **specific** problem do you have?  What is this mysterious "wall" you've hit?  Too slow?  Too fast?  Too large?  Too small?  Errors?  Out of memory?  Someone stole your hard drive?  What's the problem?

Comment: libbeanstalkclient, the C client for beanstalk is spewing errors like these -> [link](http://pastebin.com/ji32ckPH)

Comment: you aren't linking against libsbeanstalkclient. try something like `gcc -lbeanstalkclient` when compiling (add the -l... parameter)

Comment: @yossarian post it as an answer, questions without an answer usually get deleted after a year

Comment: Voted to close "too localized", on the "specific moment of time" criterion. That is, the time starting when the questioner gave up on beanstalk, until Yossarian explained the compiler erorrs.

Comment: I copied the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't linking against libsbeanstalkclient. try something like gcc -lbeanstalkclient when compiling (add the -l... parameter)

(this isn't answer on the question, but solution of questioner's problem)